# Is there any way to find corners using SkiaSharp?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I'm processing images using SkiaSharp and I'm getting good results, but I need to find corners and I do not know how to do it.

Is there any way or a function that shows me the corners detected in my image?

I have already tried with OpenCVsharp and EmguCv, but I could not do it in Xamarin Forms, It crashes, so I decided to move to Skiasharp.

Thank you

Comment: "I do not know how to do it" - in your previous question you mentioned a specific algorithm you identified that did this

Comment: Yes, I've opened the image and applied a window, but I need to look fot corners, but I have not seen a function for this in skiasharp.

Comment: you have the algorithm, you need to implement it.  SkiaSharp is not going to contain a predefined function for everything imaginable

Comment: Thanks for everything, I'll try to implement it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a function, but I found the corners applying some filters and then, looking in the image.

Here is an example of a filter:

```
using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint())
                    {
                        paint.FilterQuality = SKFilterQuality.High;
                        paint.IsAntialias = false;
                        paint.IsDither = false;
                        paint.ImageFilter = SKImageFilter.CreateMatrixConvolution(
                            sizeI, kernel, 1f, 0f, new SKPointI(1, 1),
                            SKMatrixConvolutionTileMode.Clamp, false);

                        canvas.DrawImage(image, info.Rect, ImageStretch.Uniform, paint: paint);
                        image = e.Surface.Snapshot();

                       
                    }
```

Comment: How did you calculate the kernel? What is `sizeI` variable? Can you elaborate on your solution?